# C# and EF entity won't to add as IsTempSaved to entities set

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have EF in my application written in C# and I used an `.edmx` file.

I have two collections:

```
 public virtual DbSet<Annotation> Annotations { get; set; }
 public virtual DbSet<ProductionExclusions> ProductionExclusions { get; set; }
```

and in the code I add new item as temporary item to above collections using this code:

```
public partial class Annotation: RowBase, IRow
{
        Dictionary<string, object> tempData;
    
        public void SaveTemp()
        {
            if(tempData == null)
                tempData = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            tempData["Type"] = Type;
            tempData["StartingDate"] = StartingDate;
            tempData["EndingDate"] = EndingDate;
            tempData["Description"] = Description;
        }
}

public partial class ProductionExclusions: RowBase, IRow
{
        Dictionary<string, object> tempData;
    
        public void SaveTemp()
        {
            if(tempData == null)
                tempData = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            tempData["StartingDate"] = StartingDate;
            tempData["EndingDate"] = EndingDate;
        }
}
```

and

```
var item = model.Set<ProductionExclusions>().Create();

DateTime date = DateTime.Today;

item.StartingDate = date;
item.EndingDate = date;

var entry = model.Entry(item);

if (entry.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached)
     entry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;

item.SaveTemp();

var productionExclusions = from e in model.ProductionExclusions
                           orderby e.StartingDate
                           select e;

var result = productionExclusions.ToArray();
```

And annotations is added to the `model.Annotations` with flag `IsTempSaved` but `ProductionExclusions` won't to add. `ProductionExclusions` collection is empty.
Classes `Annotation` and `ProductionExclusions` are generated by edmx.

What is the difference between these two entities that one of them adding to model set and the other won't?

In item for `Annotations` after calling method `model.Set<Annotation>().Create()` there is a property `_entityWrapper`:

[image: EntityWrapper]

In item for ProductionExclusions I don't have this property. Both of these entities using the same code to create entity.

Comment: I don't see you you saving changes to database, why do you expect to fetch your entity with query?

Comment: It's created as temporary entity: `entry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;` and should be showed in model.ProductionExclusions and have set flag `IsTempSaved = true` but isn't

Comment: I see from the code you try to fetch entities from DB with `productionExclusions.ToArray()`, but there's no such entity in DB yet. You have to perform `SaveChanges` first. The query won't return any temporary entities

Comment: Yes, you're right, I wanted to display temporary added entities in my grid, I have to create local collection, and add items from database and then add temporary created items and display this collection in grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are couple of point to verify in order to debug and fix this problem.

1. Verify both the places i.e. in DataBase and in your edmx that all fields are added correctly and updated properly.
2. check type, though it seems correct based on code. But one step to verify.
3. Try to provide hardcoded value to your object and then try.
4. At last drop your .edmx and regenerate it back.
5. set some default value just for testing to the date field.

Please try this out, you may get some help out of it.

Comment: I removed Entity from edmx and once again did Update from database and selected ProductionExclusions from wizard, but still can't add item. I added in database using INSERT one item and I can fetch it in code, but Create still doesn't work